# How to Return a File for the User to Save in an ASP.NET Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, download

I have one c# control and I am creating an image at runtime. The problem here is how do i open the file dialog when a user creates a submit button.

I have tried content-disposition but it is not working :(

---

Here is the scenario:
- I have one aspx file in that i have one ascx control file.

- In that control file's cs file i am doing some rendering and creating one image unique to that user only. After creating that image i want to display it and download it
- I have one button 'download' declared in control's html file and specified one method in the onclick event of that button

The function specified in onclick is written in cs file of that control. it is as follows:

```
public void DownloadPNG(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "text/png";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=hello.png");
    Response.Write("...");
    Response.End();
}
```

Am I doing right?. Will this call this function? Is this function right?

Comment: That is not very clear. What did you try in content disposition. What is occurring, maybe a small code example of the attempt you made.

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET application with a Submit button and you want to send an image to the user so he can use the File Save dialog to save the image to his disk?

Comment: @Kyle: four more spaces, or else get rid of the "-" for the bullets

Comment: Weird, code blocks that appear after a bullet don't render correctly.

Comment: @John yes that is what i want to do but i am using c# html javascript.

Comment: @Kyle: known "feature" - you need four extra spaces after any kind of list for the code block to be part of the list.

Comment: But what if I don't want the code block to be part of the list?  Just seems odd to me.  Saw a bunch of posts about it on meta, so it doesn't look like its going to change any time soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [`Response.WriteFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dyfzssz9.aspx) or [`Response.TransmitFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12s31dhy.aspx) or even [`Response.BinaryWrite`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.binarywrite.aspx).

Comment: Yes i was able to download a file when page loads using Response.WriteFile. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You've really given no information to figure out what you are doing.

However, if you want to make a content download as a file from an ASP.NET web page, [here's](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/asp/creating-downloadable-content-dynamically) an article I wrote that shows how to do just that.